# Should I use @Singleton, object or both with Dagger2 and Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, singleton, dagger

I'm doing an app using Kotlin and Dagger2, trying to follow the MVVM pattern, but I'm in a dilemma, should I use @Singleton, object or both? And why? Let's say I have a RepositoryMovies class and I want to get the same instance every time, according to my research you can do this as follows:

**@Singleton (Dagger2 way)**

```
@Singleton
class RepositoryMovies {
    TODO()
}
```

**Object (Kotlin way)**

```
object RepositoryMovies {
    TODO()
}
```

**Both**

```
@Singleton
object RepositoryMovies {
    TODO()
}
```

And don't get me started with singletons in Kotlin following the "Java-Way". I'd appreciate your help. Thanks so much.

Comment: I haven't used Dagger much but I think both will work. However you can have constructor parameters with a class, which might come in handy when testing to inject test resources.

Comment: As indicated in the dagger codelabs below, Google uses @Singleton with the class keyword: https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-dagger/#12

Answer (score 3):

Injecting an `object` doesn't make much sense, since in kotlin `object` is used to simulate java's utility `classes`, such as java's `Arrays` or `Collections` `classes`. One defining characteristic of such classes is that, they are not associated with any specific `class` in your project, they can be required and used anywhere.

On the other hand in most practical situations a `repository` will be associated with a specific `class`. for example you may only want to inject a `UserRepository` in a `UserViewModel`, because that is the only place where you need to access user's information.

As for the `object` and `@Singleton`, `object` is by definition a `singleton`, so marking it with `@Singleton` is redundant and doesn't accomplish anything until you make it injectable by means of a `@Provides` `function`. where you have to specify, how dagger can create `instances` of this class?

In your first example marking a class `@Singleton` doesn't do anything, unless it is injectable. as the docs state.

> ***Singletons and Scoped Bindings***
>
> ***Annotate an @Provides method or injectable class with @Singleton***. The graph will use a single instance of the value for
>   all of its clients.

Comment: RepositoryMovies is meant to be injectable, that's why it has "@Singleton" on it. I didn't find a clear solution on your answer, I still don't know what the correct aproach is. To use both seems ok, it prevents that other people create an instance of RepositoryMovies if they don't get the instance from Dagger and it follos Dagger's best practices.